# Webpack has been initialized. k6 project

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, webpack, k6

I have k6 project for run with api call. and i use nodejs so i use webpack for run k6 in project but i have error.

```
k6-api@1.0.0 start
webpack && node src/index.js
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
configuration.resolve.fallback should be one of these:
   [object { alias, name, onlyModule? }, ...] | object { <key>: [non-empty string, ...] | false | non-empty string }
   -> Redirect module requests.
   Details:
    * configuration.resolve.fallback['path'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string, ...] | false | non-empty string
      -> New request.
      Details:
       * configuration.resolve.fallback['path'] should be an array:
         [non-empty string, ...]
         -> Multiple alternative requests.
       * configuration.resolve.fallback['path'] should be false.
         -> Ignore request (replace with empty module).
       * configuration.resolve.fallback['path'] should be a non-empty string.
         -> New request.
```

This is my webpack for project, I use ES modules to project
***webpack.config.js***

```
import urlResolve from "url";
import fsResolve from "fs";
import pathResolve from "path-browserify";

export default {

    externals: {
    k6: "k6",
  },

  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      url: urlResolve,
      fs: fsResolve,
      path: pathResolve
  },
  },
};
```

***and package.json***

```
{
    "name": "k6-api",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack && node src/index.js",
        "swagger": "swagger-jsdoc -o swagger.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "k6": "^0.0.0",
        "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
        "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.8",
        "url": "^0.11.3"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.0",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
        "@types/k6": "^0.49.1",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
        "core-js": "^3.36.0",
        "webpack": "^5.90.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
    }
}
```

And i install npm or webpack , globaly in project

Comment: And your question is …? I don't see a question in your post